# Injecting a interface using variable injection in activity in android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

***Connection.kt***

```
interface Connection {
    fun connect(endpoint:String)
}
```

***HttpsConnection.kt***

```
class HttpsConnection @Inject constructor(): Connection {

    override fun connect(endpoint: String) {
        PrintUtils.printLog("HttpsConnection made")
    }

}
```

***HttpsConnectionModule.kt***

```
@Module
@DisableInstallInCheck
class `HttpsConnectionModule` {

    @Provides
    fun provideHttpsConnection() : Connection {
        return HttpsConnection()
    }

}
```

***ConnectionComponent.kt***

```
@Component(modules = [HttpsConnectionModule::class])
interface ConnectionComponent {
    fun inject(activity: IntroScopeDemoActivity)
}
```

***IntroScopeDemoActivity.kt***

```
class IntroScopeDemoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //@Inject lateinit var conn : HttpsConnection
    //@Inject lateinit var connInterface : Connection

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro_scope_demo)

        val comp = DaggerConnectionComponent.builder().build()
        comp.inject(this@IntroScopeDemoActivity)

        println("Injection completed")

    }
}
```

---

**What is Happening**

`@Inject lateinit var conn : HttpsConnection`

- If I use the above code to inject for implementation, it will work
- But if I use the below line to inject the interface, It doesn't work

`@Inject lateinit var connInterface : Connection`

---

Error:

```
/Users/devrath/Documents/Projects/Github/droid-di-use-cases/frameworks/hilt/code/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/istudio/di/modules/dagger/demos/scopes/introdemo/components/ConnectionComponent.java:9: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.sql.Connection cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ConnectionComponent {
                ^
      java.sql.Connection is injected at
          com.istudio.di.modules.dagger.demos.scopes.introdemo.IntroScopeDemoActivity.connInterface
      com.istudio.di.modules.dagger.demos.scopes.introdemo.IntroScopeDemoActivity is injected at
          com.istudio.di.modules.dagger.demos.scopes.introdemo.components.ConnectionComponent.inject(com.istudio.di.modules.dagger.demos.scopes.introdemo.IntroScopeDemoActivity)
```

---

**Question**:

Is it possible to inject the interface in the variable since the interface has an implementation-defined and attached in the component as a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check the imports in `IntroScopeDemoActivity`. Looks like `@Inject lateinit var connInterface : Connection` is from `java.sql.Connection` instead of your `Connection` interface.
2. In this case you don't need `@Provides`, you can use `@Binds` instead:

```
@Binds
fun bindHttpsConnection(impl: HttpsConnection): Connection
```

It works as you've already added `HttpsConnection` to the graph (with `@Inject constructor`), and with `@Binds` you just "map" the implementation to an interface.

As this method has only a signature and no implementation body, `HttpsConnectionModule` cannot be a regular class, but can be an interface.